# How to avoid coincidental test passing

Tags: angular, jasmine, tdd, bdd

I have the following test case:

```
it('is to show welcome message', () => {
    spyOnProperty(authServiceSpy, 'token').and.returnValue(environment.testAuthenticationToken);

    let teacher: Teacher = authServiceSpy.token.teacher;
    let welcome: HTMLElement = ne.querySelector('#welcome-msg');
    expect(welcome).toBeTruthy();
    expect(welcome.innerHTML).toEqual(`Welcome ${teacher.firstName}`);
});
```

modded `environment.testAuthenticationToken`:

```
testAuthenticationToken: {
    "type": "teacher",
    "emailVerified": true,
    "teacher": {
        "_id": "0000000000000000000000000",
        "title": "Teacher-X",
        "firstName": "X",
        "lastName": "X",
        "locale": "en-US",
        ...
        "emailVerified": true,
        ...
    }
}
```

and here is the corresponding template html

```
<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome X</div>
```

If I am using TDD and thus starting from the test then going for a minimal implementation that makes the test pass, I would hard code the name of the teacher in the HTML *`X` in this case*. The test passes although the implementation is broken for the general case. If I stopped working for the day at this and came the next day and ran the tests, I might think that since the tests pass there are probably no issues in the code.

Is this an expected outcome where refactoring is the next step that might detect it, or is using randomized expectations a way to circumvent this outcome? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If I stopped working for the day at this and came the next day and ran the tests, I might think that since the tests pass there are probably no issues in the code.

One common answer to this specific concern is to change your work routine so that there is always a failing test when you go home for the day.  The next morning, the failing test acts as a bookmark, bringing you back to the context where you were working.

You wouldn't normally publish the code in this state, of course.

When Kent Beck described TDD in his book, that process included a check list of tests he expected to write.  As new ideas occurred to him, he could take a moment to write it down, and then continue with his current work.  Tests that he later discovered weren't going to be interesting would be crossed off of the list.

Done happens when all the items on the list have been crossed off, and you can't think of any new ones to add.

If your tests are written with the goal of *also* being documentation, then it should be straight forward to read the list of implemented tests to discover gaps.  Kevlin Henney's talks on MRU lists / leap year calculations / stacks show what this might look like when problems are trivially small.

And, of course, you might also find the deficiencies by... *testing* the code.  Or be fielding bug reports the first time someone other than X uses the code (assuming that the fault leads to [failure](https://www.testingexcellence.com/error-fault-failure-software-testing/))

Answer (score 0):

This question is more related to TDD approach than its application in an angular frontend

When you do tests, "random" is the forbidden word. everything should be reproducible, unless you are not explicitly creating chaos on purpose: this is what [mutation testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) does and helps to catch some useless test or some case in which a wrong implementation would be not detected from a test

But, keeping the feet on the ground, i propose this example

```
describe("authServer.login()" , () => {
    it("should return true if the user exists and password valid" , () => {

        let result = uut.login("VALIDUSER" , "VALIDPASSWORD")

        expect(result).to.be.true
    })
})
```

I would make this test pass simply with

```
function login (username, password) {
     return true
}
```

Now, how i can be forced to change that implementation to make something valuable in my function?

**1) don't start from happy path**

Often, when  we write new code, we start from happy path then we add all needed exception (not intendend as software exception :-D ) handling. This is not wrong at all, in fact is a very agile-minded approach because lets you write some working code without stressing your mind thinking everything upfront. But, if we are able and lucky, sometimes it is not so difficult to split our code in many little components and design their behaviour upfront. In the login case is much easy to start from

```
describe("authServer.login()" , () => {
    it("should return false if the user doesnt exists" , () => {

        let result = uut.login("NOTFOUNDUSER" , "VALIDPASSWORD")

        expect(result).to.be.false
    })
})

function login (username, password) {
     return false
}
```

but, since you're not happy from your path, you have to change it

**2) "Expect More" from your Code**

It's a contreived argument, Uncle Bob wrote about it in its "Clean Code": is it a good practice to include more than one assertion in a test? I'm not better than the people involved in this debate but I can notiche that every set of data on which is defined a function can be divided in "equivalence classes", since the function that developers write are not injective, so adding two asserts from the same equivalence class is just like having one, but with more constraints

```
describe("sum()" , () => {
    it("should sum correctly two addends , () => {

        expect(sum(3,7)).to.eq(10)
        expect(sum(1,2)).to.eq(3)
    })
})
```

now you cannot hardcorde a number anymore. You can then get rid of one of the two if it really bothers you

**3) Refactoring is not just writing code better**

But also make it working while it doesn't change its black box behaviour. After you made a test pass with your baby step, you **must** go back to the code to have a review, it's the tdd cycle! in this case you will notice that the production code is a scam and you will work on it. f you don't have time because your teammate are pressing you to go to lunch, mess up your test on purpose before to push

```
describe("authServer.login()" , () => {
    it("should return true if the user exists and password valid" , () => {

        let result = uut.login("VALIDUSER" , "VALIDPASSWORD")

        expect(result).to.be.true
        expect(true).to.be.false //<----- Have a Nice meal
    })
})
```

Aside from that, remember that in TDD tests are a living thing, they change with the code and you can leverage it